# Manually Add Audit Entry to Hibernate Envers

Tags: java, hibernate-envers

I am auditing a Java object using Hibernate Envers annotations, but initial object creation occurs directly in the database using Pentaho (ETL).

I want to create the object using ETL and add a table entry to the Envers generated object_AUD and REVINFO tables.

I have been trying to find the generation strategy for the REV column from the REVINFO table, but I must be looking in the wrong places.  Would someone help me find an effective generation strategy so I can manually insert records into the audited tables without causing possible collisions or weird behavior in the future?

Answer (score 3):

What you seek is going to depend on whether or not you are configuring your application to take the default for `org.hibernate.envers.use_revision_entity_with_native_id`.

The default value (`true`) tells Envers to ask Hibernate to create the `REVINFO` table using a native-based primary key which will either be `IDENTITY` or `SEQUENCE` depending upon your database platform.  If you look at the table definition for `REVINFO` in  your database, you should be able to deduce this information.

If this property is configured using `false`, Envers will construct its own sequence metadata and provide that to Hibernate.  The sequence is called `REVISION_NUMBER` and is stored in a table called `REVISION_GENERATOR`.  The sequence is initialized to 1 and incremented by 1 as the default.